# DataMapper migrating column to a new data type

Tags: mysql, ruby, datamapper

Issue is that I can't change a column type to 'Text'

This is the error I am seeing:

DarkBook:playground Justin$ rake migrate_up  (in /Users/Justin/Dropbox/Business/datamapper/playground)   ~ Starting Migration   == Performing Up Migration #1: create_person_table     CREATE TABLE `people` (`id` SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, `name` VARCHAR(2),  `age` INTEGER) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE  utf8_general_ci     -> 0.0112s   -> 0.0129s   == Performing Up Migration #2: change_name_constraints  rake aborted!  uninitialized constant SQL::TableModifier::Text  /Users/Justin/Dropbox/Business/datamapper/playground/rakefile.rb:61:in  `block (3 levels) in '  (See full trace by running task with --trace) 
Rake script I'm using to test DataMapper:  https://gist.github.com/818143 
It **seems** as though the change_column method within the  TableModifier class isn't converting the column change statement to  MySQL correctly. Other seemingly related errors are that if I try to  convert a column to a String of longer length I get this: 
DarkBook:playground Justin$ rake migrate_up  (in /Users/Justin/Dropbox/Business/datamapper/playground)   ~ Starting Migration   == Performing Up Migration #2: change_name_constraints

ALTER TABLE `people` ALTER COLUMN `name` TYPE String

~ You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use  near 'TYPE String' at line 1 (code: 1064, sql state: 42000, query:  ALTER TABLE `people` ALTER COLUMN `name` TYPE String, uri:  mysql://root:@127.0.0.1datamapper_test)  rake aborted!  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use  near 'TYPE String' at line 1

/Users/Justin/Dropbox/Business/datamapper/playground/rakefile.rb:60:in  `block (2 levels) in '  (See full trace by running task with --trace)

According to what I've read about MySQL, "ALTER TABLE `people` ALTER  COLUMN `name` TYPE String" is not a valid MySQL query command. TYPE  shouldn't be there and String should be converted to VARCHAR.

Looking inside the change_column method I see it's just a straight  pass through of the type I'm providing. This is making me think  perhaps I'm not supposed to be calling the change_column method  directly?

Once I get this figured out and I'm well on my way, I'm documenting  this stuff as figuring out DataMapper's migration api has been  hellish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change_column` isn't particularly bright. The current implementation is:

```
def change_column(name, type, opts = {})
  @statements << "ALTER TABLE #{quoted_table_name} ALTER COLUMN #{quote_column_name(name)} TYPE #{type}"
end
```

Meaning you need to specify the underlying sql type rather than a DataMapper type. To wit:

```
modify_table :people do
  change_column :name, 'text'
end
```

I will update the documentation to include this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around I found:
https://gist.github.com/819792